# Is there a possibility to do CSS Coverage for multiple screen sizes in one session?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to create CSS Coverage Report with Puppeteer. It works fine for one screen size / device at a time. But I want to do it for multiple screen sizes in one run, so I have one report at the end and can parse it to create one CSS file for all screen sizes. The parsing is not the problem, but rather the report contains only the results of last device / screen size.

I hoped something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const deviceDescriptors = require('puppeteer/DeviceDescriptors');

const coverage = async (host, pageSlug, device) => {
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: [
      `--window-size=${device.width},${device.height}`
    ]
  });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: device.width,
    height: device.height
  });

  await page.coverage.startCSSCoverage({ resetOnNavigation: false });

  await page.goto(host + '/' + pageSlug + '?fullcss');
  await page.emulate(deviceDescriptors['iPhone 7']);
  await page.reload();
  let cssCoverage = await page.coverage.stopCSSCoverage();

  await browser.close();
  return cssCoverage;
};
```

Is it even theoretically possible? Since media queries are missing in the result anyway, even if I had the "full" report, the styles for mobile and desktop would all be there in a single file without media queries. Has anybody tried to do something like this?

Comment: Any chance you would share your code? I'm struggling with getting multiple URLs out of coverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to run the reports one after another like this:

```js
// the configs you want to test
const configs = [
  {host: '...', pageSlug: '...', device: { /* ... */ } },
  {host: '...', pageSlug: '...', device: { /* ... */ } },
  {host: '...', pageSlug: '...', device: { /* ... */ } },
];

const coverage = async ({ host, pageSlug, device }) => {
  // ... your code
};

const results = [];

for(const config of configs) {
  const result = await coverage(config);
  results.push(result);
}
```

After execution, the variable `results` would contain the test results.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up with a similar solution.

Comment: @AleksandrEpp : Were u able to get the `@media` query style CSS rules using puppeteer?